# Rails 3 + Exception notifier: How do I use exception notifier for rake tasks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception

So in the old plugin for Rails 2 there used to be a method called `notifiable` that I could use to surround whatever Rake task I needed to attach exception notifier to. However, when I try to run my rake task it gives me an undefined method error. I looked around and noticed someone else use the `exception_notify` method and tried replacing this:

```
task(:create_orders_for => :environment) do
  notifiable do
    ...
  end
end
```

with this:

```
exception_notify {:create_orders_for => :environment} do
  #notifiable do
    ...
end
```

But it doesn't work. Does anyone know what the Rails 3 version of this method is? I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is what I eventually ended up doing. Works great.

1. Add the middleware configuration to your environment/whatever_environment_you_want.rb file
2. If you're testing in dev or test, you need to set the consider_all_requests_local to `false`
3. Change your rake task to this:

   ```
   task(:create_orders_for => :environment) do
   begin
     ...
   rescue => e
     ExceptionNotifier::Notifier.exception_notification(Rails.env, e).deliver
   end
   ```

   end